# How long does Apple provide support and updates for a specific iOS version?

Tags: ios, security, software-update

Does Apple list any guidelines for how long a consumer might expect to be supported with the version of iOS that ships with Apple hardware at the time of purchase?

On [computer OS there seems to be a n-2 support pattern](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47664/what-is-apples-policy-for-supporting-security-updates-on-older-versions-of-os-x). You can buy AppleCare for 3 years of [software support](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61380/how-long-does-apple-provide-support-for-mac-os-x) (in most cases) and the previous 2 versions get routine and prompt security updates along with the latest shipping OS.

On iOS there seems to be an n-1 support pattern. You can buy AppleCare for 2 years of software support and security updates seem to be released for the two most recent versions.

Has anyone seen an Apple document or compelling evidence that there is a policy in place for this when considering iOS deployment planning?

Comment: Nope, it is not a policy it is a competitive business decision.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Is that something you can source or just a feeling / educated guess?

Comment: It comes from personal experience in the similar business of product support.